# Are the pseudomonotone operators $A$ such that $-A$ is also pseudomonotone?

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, monotone-functions

> Does there exists a pseudomonotone operator $A: V \to V^*$, where $V$ is a (real reflexive, separable) Banach space such that $-A$ is also pseudomonotone?

An operator is called pseudomontone if $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n - u \rangle \le 0$ implies that $\langle A u, u - w \rangle \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n - w \rangle$ holds for all $w \in V$.

**Here's what I figured out so far:** if such an operator exists then $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ and $\langle A u_n, u_n - u \rangle \to 0$ imply that $\langle A u_n, u_n - w \rangle \to \langle A u, u - w \rangle$ for all $w \in V$, since we have
$$
\limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle -A u_n, u_n - u \rangle \le 0
\iff \liminf_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n - u \rangle \ge 0
$$
and
$$
\langle -A u, u - w \rangle \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} \langle -A u_n, u_n - w \rangle
\iff \langle A u, u - w \rangle \ge \limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n - w \rangle.
$$
Now if $\limsup_{n \to \infty} a_n \le b \le \liminf_{n \to \infty} a_n$ for any real sequence $(a_n)_n$ we have $a_n \to b$.

So in summary we have

- $u_n \rightharpoonup{} u$
- $\langle A u_n, u_n - u \rangle \to 0 = \langle A u, u - u \rangle$
- $\langle A u_n, u_n - w \rangle \to \langle A u, u - w \rangle$ for all $w \in V$.

**Do such operators exist and can they be characterised in a good way?**

**Edit**
We also have the following alternative characterisation of pseudomonotone operators:

A bounded operator $A$ is pseudomonotone if and only if, from $u_n \rightharpoonup u$ in $V$ and $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \langle A u_n, u_n - u \rangle \le 0$ it follows that $A u_n \rightharpoonup A u$ and $\langle A u_n, u_n \rangle \to \langle A u, u \rangle$ hold.

Comment: What about $A=0$?

Comment: @daw $A = 0$ works but is it the only solution?

Comment: Every constant $A$ is pseudomonotone, isn't it? And I think every compact linear $A \colon V \to V^{\ast}$ is pseudomonotone (but I haven't checked).

Comment: @DanielFischer The second statement is correct. One can even make this more precise: Call $A: V \to V^*$ weak-strong continuous if $u_n \rightharpoonup u \implies A u_n \to Au$. Then we have linear and compact $\implies$ weak-strong continuous $\implies$ pseudomontone. Also monotone and radially continuous operators are pseudomonotone.

Comment: If $V$ is finite-dimensional or more generally has the Schur property, then every continuous map $A:V \to V^\ast$ is pseudomonotone, since weak convergence of a sequence implies strong convergence. Therefore every continuous map is an example. To make the question non-trivial, a requirement such as unboundedness of  $A$ or "weak convergence $\ne$ norm convergence"   should be added.

Comment: Here is another class of examples: $A$ maps weakly convergent sequences to weakly convergent sequences, and $\langle Au, u \rangle = 0$ for all $u \in V$. Linearity of $A$ is not required.

Comment: @HansEngler $V$ must not be finite dimensional and $A$ can be nonlinear. I am not searching for a specific example, but a general statement. For example: if $A$ and $-A$ are monotone, $A$ must be constant.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik - How about a rotation by $90^o$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$? $A$ and $-A$ are monotone but $A$ is non-trivial.